# Firestore custom objects in .jar shared by Java server and Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using Firestore and in my project I have a Java server and an Android app that both currently share a common datamodel library/.jar.  The problem is I can't figure out how to use any Firestore annotations like @Exclude or @ServerTimestamp in the datamodel classes, because the datamodel library needs to depend on two conflicting packages (one for the Android flavor of Firestore, one for the Java flavor):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0'
```

Is there some Gradle magic I can do to make sure the datamodel only depends on the bare minimum (the Annotation definitions)?

If so, I can add something like:

```
private @com.google.firebase.database.Exclude @com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.Exclude String sentBy;
```

Right now I'm getting the following error:

```
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 5.8.0, 11.8.0. Examples include com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvites:11.8.0
```

Comment: It seems to me, for now, that you'll have to maintain two different but similar versions of the data model for each environment.

Comment: Oh no @DougStevenson!! I'm pretty sure the OOP/reusability gods will strike me down if I do that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  Full transparency...this is somewhat of a hack, but it works.  Essentially you give your datamodel library just enough to compile standalone, then pull in the full Firestore dependencies in your respective Android and server projects.

In your **datamodel** library:
a) Make packages that exactly mock the annotations you need.  Just copy the contents of the annotation classes into Exclude, ServerTimestamp, etc.
b) Then make sure you do **NOT** have any Firestore dependencies in your Gradle/POM.
c) Tag classes, fields and methods with **both** the Android and server annotations.

[image: datamodel project structure]

[image: datamodel tagging fields]

In your **Android** project, include your datamodel library/project, but **exclude** the dummy Android annotations your datamodel compiled against. With the Firestore library your Android app depends on, all those dependencies will be satisfied by the real classes in that library.

[image: Android gradle]

Do the same in your **server** project, but **exclude** the dummy server annotations your datamodel compiled against.

**Result**: All projects should compile and the fields should be excluded, etc as expected by Firestore, and you won't have to keep 2 versions of your Java datamodel.

**Note**: If the annotations classes are ever changed, you will have to update your annotation classes.  However, that seems like it would happen very rarely, and is a good tradeoff for not having to keep 2 copies of all your Java datamodel.